# Getting the number of affected rows for a SQLite statement using the C API

Tags: c, sqlite, sql-delete, rows-affected

I'm executing a `DELETE` statement using the SQLite 3 C API, and I'd like to know how to fetch the number of affected rows.

Unfortunately, there is no function such as `sqlite3_affected_rows` or similar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [sqlite3_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) and/or [sqlite3_total_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/total_changes.html)

Answer (score 10):

Run this.

```
select changes(),total_changes();
```

> The changes() function returns the number of database rows that were changed or inserted or deleted **by the most recently completed** INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE **statement**

> The total_changes() function returns the number of row changes caused by INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements **since the current database connection was opened**.

(emphasis added)

Comment: You should add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to use `rowcount`, it is just an example function for DELETE statement.

```
def delete_data():
    """Deletes data from database based on id given"""
    print("you have choosen to DELETE data!!!")
    print("")
    id = input ("enter id: ")
    # cursor.execute always return number of affected row for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
    record_number = cursor.execute("delete from student where id = ?", [id])
    # this is the row number that is deleted by database, it is kept in this parameter
    if record_number.rowcount > 0:
        print("your data ({} row) has been DELETED successfully!!!".format(record_number.rowcount))
    else:
        print("No data found for id {}".format(id))
    print("")
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Also see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978931/python-retrieve-number-of-rows-affected-with-sql-delete-query).