# Python: retrieve number of rows affected with SQL DELETE query

Tags: python, sqlite

It seems it is quite easy to retrieve the number of rows `SELECT`ed with a SQL query with

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from ...")
result=cursor.fetchone()
```

but how should I retrieve the number of rows by a `DELETE` query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "rows affected" functionality is implemented via [`cursor.rowcount`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount):

```
cursor.execute("DELETE from ...")
result = cursor.rowcount
```

---

Demo:

```
In [1]: import sqlite3

In [2]: db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

In [3]: cursor = db.cursor()

In [4]: cursor.execute("create table test(i)")
Out[4]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x103a3c260>

In [5]: cursor.execute("insert into test(i) values (1)")
Out[5]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x103a3c260>

In [6]: cursor.execute("insert into test(i) values (2)")
Out[6]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x103a3c260>

In [7]: cursor.execute("insert into test(i) values (3)")
Out[7]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x103a3c260>

In [8]: cursor.execute("delete from test where i >= 2")
Out[8]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x103a3c260>

In [9]: cursor.rowcount
Out[9]: 2
```